# PHP bookend a string if true

Tags: php, shortcut

I feel like there must be simpler way to do this, but sometimes I want two pieces of text at different points if one case is true.

Here, I'm wrapping stuff in a link in two different ways.  They both seem long.

```
<?=($x)?"<a href='$x'>":""?> stuff <?=($x)?"</a>":""?>
```

or

```
$y = "stuff";
if ($x)
  $y = "<a href='$x'>$y</a>";
print $y;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with ternary operator

```
echo (isset($x))?"<a href='$x'>$y</a>":$y;
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/WbIacO